# Dealing with posts containing multiple questions

Tags: discussion, editing, close-reasons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with multiple questions asked in one?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335/how-to-deal-with-multiple-questions-asked-in-one)

When faced with a question which *clearly* contains multiple questions within it (eg, the asker even says "I have X questions. Here they are:1,2,3...) I think we can all agree that the question needs to change. Is it more appropriate to vote/flag to close the question as Not A Real Question and wait for the OP to edit it, or should one immediately edit out every question past the first one and comment recommending that the OP open more posts?

Does the answer to this question depend if the user is brand new (and may never show up to edit) or not? Does it depend if the editor/closer is also a moderator (whose close vote is binding) or not?